# What are possible reasons for the error: Value of type "x" has no subscripts?

Tags: swift

This is my code. I have gone through it but can't seem to fix the error. What I need to do is get firebase information from the database and display it on my screen.

```
class homepage:UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
var people = [Userx]()

public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return people.count
}

public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    let people: Userx


    people = people[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblName.text = people.Education
    cell.lblgenre.text = people.WhatIamConsideringBuying

    return cell


}



@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

 override func viewDidLoad() {

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign Out", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(signOut))

super.viewDidLoad()

let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("Education").observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in

    if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
        self.people.removeAll()
        for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"]
            let peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying = peopleObject?["WhatIamConsideringBuying"]
            let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]
            let people = Userx(Education: peopleEducation as! String?, WhatIamConsideringBuying: peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying as! String?, PhotoPosts: peoplePhotoPosts as AnyObject)
                self.people.append(people)

        }
        self.table.reloadData()

    }

})
```

//Here is the Userx in a different file:

```
class Userx {
var Education: String?
var WhatIamConsideringBuying: String?
var PhotoPosts: AnyObject?

init(Education: String?, WhatIamConsideringBuying: String?, PhotoPosts: AnyObject? ){

self.Education = Education
    self.WhatIamConsideringBuying = WhatIamConsideringBuying
    self.PhotoPosts = PhotoPosts
}
```

Once I'm done I want the firebase data to be fetched and displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you override the instance property `people` with a local variable of another type, `Userx` instead of `[Userx]` in `cellForRowAt`. You should give another name to your local variable.

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    let person: Userx = people[indexPath.row]

    cell.lblName.text = person.Education
    cell.lblgenre.text = person.WhatIamConsideringBuying

    return cell
}
```

Unrelated to your problem, but you should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names and use immutable non-Optional values where possible. Using a `struct` instead of a `class` also gives you an auto-synthetised memberwise initializer, so you don't need to create one yourself. You should also try to not use `Any` or `AnyObject` when you know the type a variable should hold (which should be the case in most situations).

```
class Userx {
    let education: String
    let whatIamConsideringBuying: String
    let photoPosts: AnyObject
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes sense. I still get an error AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'. I've never had an App Delegate error before. Do you know what might be causing it?

Comment: @user9269956 that error seems to be unrelated to the code in your question. You should ask a new question with a [mcve] about that other issue.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a curly brace in this file in the init

**Your code**

```
class Userx {
var Education: String?
var WhatIamConsideringBuying: String?
var PhotoPosts: AnyObject?

init(Education: String?, WhatIamConsideringBuying: String?, PhotoPosts: AnyObject? ){

self.Education = Education
    self.WhatIamConsideringBuying = WhatIamConsideringBuying
    self.PhotoPosts = PhotoPosts
}
```

Fixed Code

```
   class Userx {
    var Education: String?
    var WhatIamConsideringBuying: String?
    var PhotoPosts: AnyObject?

    init(Education: String?, WhatIamConsideringBuying: String?, PhotoPosts: AnyObject? ){

    self.Education = Education
        self.WhatIamConsideringBuying = WhatIamConsideringBuying
        self.PhotoPosts = PhotoPosts
    }
}
```

Comment: That is most probably a copy-paste error and even if not, that's definitely not the reason for that specific compile-time error.